# Sql execution order

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I am confusing with simple query:

```
SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE name = 'stack';
```

My question is this which part first execute:

```
SELECT * FROM table_name
```

OR

```
WHERE name = 'stack'
```

First select all record from table then filter with WHERE condition **or** 
first filter records then SELECT?

For more details about question please see this link:

[WHERE condition issue in SQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20464587/where-condition-issue-in-sql/20464683?noredirect=1#20464683)

Thanks

Comment: Err, neither and/or both? It's a hell of a lot more complex than just "it does the select first" vs "it does the where" first.

Comment: I'm confused as to what the purpose of this question is? What are you looking to use the answer of this for?

Comment: why do you need to know? What are you trying to figure out?

Comment: Please see my question here:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20464587/where-condition-issue-in-sql/20464683?noredirect=1#20464683

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The following steps show the logical processing order, or binding order, for a SELECT statement. This order determines when the objects defined in one step are made available to the clauses in subsequent steps. For example, if the query processor can bind to (access) the tables or views defined in the FROM clause, these objects and their columns are made available to all subsequent steps. Conversely, because the SELECT clause is step 8, any column aliases or derived columns defined in that clause cannot be referenced by preceding clauses. However, they can be referenced by subsequent clauses such as the ORDER BY clause. Note that the actual physical execution of the statement is determined by the query processor and the order may vary from this list.

```
    FROM
    ON
    JOIN
    WHERE
    GROUP BY
    WITH CUBE or WITH ROLLUP
    HAVING
    SELECT
    DISTINCT
    ORDER BY
    TOP
```

Comment: my co-worker takes the line `Note that the actual physical execution of the statement is determined by the query processor and the order may vary from this list.` to say that -- really -- we have no idea how our SQL queries will ever run until we run and test them, and we have can throw out your whole binding list because it's not even true. What to say to such a person? Do you have a source for this "logical processing order"?

Comment: heh I asked for a source... well your whole answer is pasted from https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189499.aspx

Answer (score 0):

It selects all the records first from the table and then filter in sequence according to the condition or conditions specified.