# WHERE condition issue in SQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I am facing problem with an SQL query:

Here is my table data:

```
+------------+--------+--------+------------+------------+
| priceId_PK | mPrice | aPrice | validFrom  | validTo    |
+------------+--------+--------+------------+------------+
|          1 |   0.00 |   0.00 | 2013-07-01 | 2013-08-31 |
|          2 |   7.50 |   2.50 | 2013-09-01 | 2013-12-31 |
|          3 |  15.00 |   5.00 | 2014-01-01 | 2035-12-31 |
+------------+--------+--------+------------+------------+
```

And my SQL query is

```
SELECT mPrice, aPrice, 

CASE 
    WHEN validFrom < '2013-11-01' 
        THEN '2013-11-01' 
    ELSE validFrom END AS validFrom, 

CASE 
    WHEN validTo > '2013-11-30' 
        THEN '2013-11-30' 
    ELSE validTo END AS validTo 

FROM commission 

WHERE (validfrom BETWEEN '2013-11-01' AND '2013-11-30' OR validto BETWEEN '2013-11-01' AND '2013-11-30') ORDER BY validFrom
```

My expected result:

```
+--------+--------+------------+------------+
| mPrice | aPrice | validFrom  | validTo    |
+--------+--------+------------+------------+
|   7.50 |   2.50 | 2013-11-01 | 2013-11-30 |
+--------+--------+------------+------------+
```

But the query actually returns an empty set.

Without the `WHERE` condition, the query is

```
SELECT mPrice, aPrice, 

CASE 
    WHEN validFrom < '2013-11-01' 
        THEN '2013-11-01' 
    ELSE validFrom END AS validFrom, 

CASE 
    WHEN validTo > '2013-11-30' 
        THEN '2013-11-30' 
    ELSE validTo END AS validTo 

FROM commission
```

This returns:

```
+--------+--------+------------+------------+
| mPrice | aPrice | validFrom  | validTo    |
+--------+--------+------------+------------+
|   0.00 |   0.00 | 2013-11-01 | 2013-08-31 |
|   7.50 |   2.50 | 2013-11-01 | 2013-11-30 |
|  15.00 |   5.00 | 2014-01-01 | 2013-11-30 |
+--------+--------+------------+------------+
```

My question is, Why does the query with the `WHERE` condition return empty data when I expect it to return a single result set?

Is it a problem with [the execution order of `SELECT` and `WHERE` conditions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20425808/sql-execution-order)?

Or is it another issue with `WHERE` condition that is not working properly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you are trying to access the `validFrom`  and  `validTo`  from the case query in the where condition. If that is the case, you need to reformat your query.

```
SELECT t1.* FROM ( SELECT mPrice, aPrice, 
CASE 
    WHEN validFrom < '2013-11-01' 
        THEN '2013-11-01' 
    ELSE validFrom END AS validFrom, 

CASE 
    WHEN validTo > '2013-11-30' 
        THEN '2013-11-30' 
    ELSE validTo END AS validTo 

FROM commission) t1 

WHERE ((t1.validfrom BETWEEN '2013-11-01' AND '2013-11-30') OR (t1.validto BETWEEN '2013-11-01' AND '2013-11-30')) ORDER BY t1.validFrom
```

But this will return 3 results. If you need to get the expected result, then you need to use an `AND` condition instead of `OR`.

Then your query will be

```
SELECT t1.* FROM ( SELECT mPrice, aPrice, 
CASE 
    WHEN validFrom < '2013-11-01' 
        THEN '2013-11-01' 
    ELSE validFrom END AS validFrom, 

CASE 
    WHEN validTo > '2013-11-30' 
        THEN '2013-11-30' 
    ELSE validTo END AS validTo 

FROM commission) t1 

WHERE ((t1.validfrom BETWEEN '2013-11-01' AND '2013-11-30') AND (t1.validto BETWEEN '2013-11-01' AND '2013-11-30')) ORDER BY t1.validFrom
```

Comment: Sabari: I want to know why my query return empty data set.

Comment: @KajalSingh your query returned empty because your original table data does not have any values between '2013-11-01' AND '2013-11-30' for validFrom or validTo fields. You are altering the data output using case condition in the query. You are trying to access the same in the query end which is not possible. If you check your original table data there is not values between the dates you mentioned

Comment: @KajalSingh if you need to get the output as you desire, then you need to reformat as I have explained to you.

Comment: @KajalSingh :-) let me know if you need any more clarifications.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this, added proper `()` for validfrom and validto columns

```
WHERE ( (validfrom BETWEEN '2013-11-01' AND '2013-11-30') OR (validto BETWEEN '2013-11-01' AND '2013-11-30') ) ORDER BY validFrom
```

Comment: It's also returing empty data.

Answer (score 0):

have you try this....

```
SELECT mPrice, aPrice, 

CASE 
    WHEN validFrom < '2013-11-01' 
        THEN '2013-11-01' 
    ELSE validFrom END AS validFrom, 

CASE 
    WHEN validTo > '2013-11-30' 
        THEN '2013-11-30' 
    ELSE validTo END AS validTo 

FROM commission 

WHERE (validfrom BETWEEN '2013-11-01' AND '2013-11-30') OR (validto BETWEEN '2013-11-01' AND '2013-11-30') ORDER BY validFrom
```

Comment: It's also returing empty data

Answer (score 0):

Try like this,

```
WHERE 
((validfrom BETWEEN '2013-11-01' AND '2013-11-30') OR 
(validto BETWEEN '2013-11-01' AND '2013-11-30')) 
ORDER BY validFrom
```

Comment: Also return empty data.

Comment: valid from & valid to dates are date data types or varchar ?

Comment: aditya: Both field data type is: date

Comment: Why dont you try simple like this, [   SELECT mPrice, aPrice, validFrom, validTo  From Comission where {here goes where condition} ]

Comment: Most probably the error is with the date limits, try to increase the date limit & check, whether the query is improper or the dates specified are improper.

Answer (score 0):

I got useful data from Google about my question.

> Standard SQL doesn't allow you to refer to a column alias in a WHERE
>   clause. This restriction is imposed because when the WHERE code is
>   executed, the column value may not yet be determined.
>
> You can only use column aliases in GROUP BY, ORDER BY, or HAVING
>   clauses.